# Moving compiled executable file to another system with different page size

Tags: memory-management

what if a compiled executable file were to be move from a system with 4KB page size to another system with a 8KB page size? Does the file needs to be recompiled?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on the executable file format, the ABI, and the operating system.

Comment: Is the difference in page size a factor as well?